# Zend Framework 2:Argument 1 passed to Album\Controller\AlbumController::__construct() must be an instance of Album\Controller\AlbumTable

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting an error as ;

```
Argument 1 passed to Album\Controller\AlbumController::__construct() must be an instance of Album\Controller\AlbumTable, instance of Album\Model\AlbumTable given,, called in /var/www/html/zf/module/Album/src/Module.php on line 43
```

My Module.php is;

```
<?php
  namespace Album;

  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
  use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
  use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
  use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
  use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
  use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}

// Add this method:
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway);
            },
            Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album());
                return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ],
    ];
}

public function getControllerConfig()
{
   return [
           'factories' => [
           Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) {
                 return new Controller\AlbumController(
                     $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                 );
             },
          ],
      ];
   }
}
```

My AlbumController is like;

```
<?php
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Album\Model;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
// Add this property:
private $table;

// Add this constructor:
public function __construct(AlbumTable $table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
}

public function indexAction()
{
  return new ViewModel([
        'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
    ]);
}

public function addAction()
{
}

public function editAction()
{
}

public function deleteAction()
{
}
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am very new in Zend Framework. It is the tutorial application I am trying to run.I followed all steps but there were a lot of issues and I solved all those one by one , now I am stuck here.

Comment: So what about that error message is in any way cryptic or difficult to understand?

Comment: I have mentioned the error. It is easy one to understand what is the error. But can not understand the solution.

Comment: conclusion : `must be an instance of Album\Controller\AlbumTable, instance of Album\Model\AlbumTable given`

Comment: Yes I understand, I have added the AlbumController class , can you please check what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using illegal dependency so to speak,

```
// Here you are returning Model\AlbumTable object
// while your Controller\AlbumController needs a Controller\AlbumTable instance
return new Controller\AlbumController(
    $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
);
```

so to solve this :

```
return new Controller\AlbumController(
    $container->get(Controller\AlbumTable::class)
);
```

---

in case if you need to use Model\AlbumTable as a dependency, so you will need to set it in your controller as follows :

```
use Model\AlbumTable as AlbumTableModel;

...
...

public function __construct(AlbumTableModel $table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the AlbumTable class in `AlbumController.php`.

`use Album\Model\AlbumTable;`